# How to get notification of a context switch in Windows (7)

Tags: multithreading, windows-7, context-switch

For some RTOS's, there is some event, or even a callout function that is called when the kernel is switching into, or even switching out of a thread. In pSOS it was called the TaskSwitchCallout. In this we would have code to increment counters whereby we knew how much CPU time a thread was taking. In Qnx, you can subscribe to an event that occurs when the kernel has switched in a task and perform the same counter increment.

Is there an equivalent in Windows? Often under Windows we cannot determine when exactly a thread context has been switched in or out of relative to other threads running in the system (read:managed code).

Please don't ask why I'm trying to do this, I can't talk about it. However I can say that the context switch counter in Windows perfmon is not sufficient. But I figure that the context switch counter in perfmon must get it's information from somewhere... I'm trying to access that somewhere on a per thread basis.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't believe there's such a thing... Windows is nothing near an RTOS and AFAIK it just wasn't designed to send a notification like that. (It seems like that would dramatically slow down the system, no?)

Comment: There is [QueryThreadCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684943(v=vs.85).aspx) - would this help?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not notify threads of context switches.

If you want timing information, use [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [QueryThreadCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or one of the performance counters.

Alternatively, you could make use of the Windows 7 User-mode scheduler, so you are in charge of the context switches: [User-mode scheduling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)